# Why is my gitignore not ignoring these untracked files?

Tags: git, directory, version-control, gitignore

This may seem like a duplicate question but I have tried the solutions proposed to similar question, but am not seeing the desired results.

I'm expecting this line in my .giignore

[image: yes]

to ignore these files

[image: yess]

The problem is that the files are staying as untracked and not being ignored. I have never added them to git yet, so doing `git rm --cached` doesn't do anything

I also do want to keep tracking the .gitkeep in order to track the directory, but not the other files

How can I make this work?

Comment: What distinction are you drawing between "untracked" and "ignored"?  What are you expecting `git rm --cached` to do regarding the untracked files?

Comment: If you were using `git status`, for example, you could suppress its *reporting* of untracked files using the `git status -uno`, but that's different from *ignoring* the files.

Comment: Whatever GUI you are using may have an option to omit displaying the untracked files, but keep in mind a subtle distinction: it is displaying files in a directory, not objects in your repository. (Each file is associated with an object belonging to the current checkout, which is how the GUI can associate an object's status with a file.)

Comment: there is a very big difference between ignored and untracked files

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following steps:

Run the command `git status`.

**If the files are displayed in the output:**

Files aren't being ignored. Make sure they haven't been staged by running `git reset <fileName>` (this un-stages a file).

**If the files are *not* displayed in the output:**

The issue must be a result of the design of the GUI itself, and nothing to do with Git. This is because `git status` has clearly shown that the files aren't being perceived by Git.

Comment: the files are present and unstaged, but still showing as being untracked rather than ignored

Comment: Did you run the git status command? In a terminal?

Comment: Also, I doubt this would make a difference, but to ignore a directory, you don't need the asterisk (*) at the end. I always just do `folder/` not `folder/*`. Maybe try removing the asterisk?